# How to query text[] column in Supabase?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I want to retrieve rows based on a value being present in text column defined as multidimensional array in Supabase

Table looks like following
[image]

I am trying to query this records using following urls

[https://DATABASE_URL.supabase.co/rest/v1/test_db?data=in.({"1"})](https://DATABASE_URL.supabase.co/rest/v1/test_db?data=in.(%7B%221%22%7D))

https://DATABASE_URL.supabase.co/rest/v1/test_db?data=in.(1)

But doesnt seem to work. Error message was `operator does not exist: text[] ~~ unknown`
with hint being `No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter by the values inside of an array, you can use the `cs` operator, which is equivalent to `@>` (contains) in PostgreSQL.

For instance, this query will retrieve all the rows that have the value `"1"` present in the array of the `data` column.

```
https://DATABASE_URL.supabase.co/rest/v1/test_db?data=cs.{"1"}
```

Comment: Also, can you point where in docs you found this. I can't seem to find it

Comment: @Yash Yes, there isn't an example on how to use it, but it's in the [list of operators](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=cs#operators) in the PostgREST docs.